# How to extract unique characters used from a vector of type character?

Tags: r

So I have a vector like the following:

```
test <- c("ASSFGH","PSSWEE","ASSYNT","ASSFRK","ASSFGT","ASSRTV")
```

I want to output a list of letter that are used in all of these strings, but these letters to show up only once in the final output.

How can this be done?

Thanks!

Comment: `table(strsplit(paste0(test, collapse = ""),""))`

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
library(tidyverse)

test %>% 
  str_extract_all(boundary("character")) %>% 
  unlist() %>% 
  unique()
```

Which returns:

```
 [1] "A" "S" "F" "G" "H" "P" "W" "E" "Y" "N" "T" "R" "K" "V"
```

Alternatively:

```
test %>% 
  str_extract_all(boundary("character")) %>% 
  unlist() %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  count(value)

# A tibble: 14 x 2
   value     n
   <chr> <int>
 1     A     5
 2     E     2
 3     F     3
 4     G     2
 5     H     1
 6     K     1
 7     N     1
 8     P     1
 9     R     2
10     S    12
11     T     3
12     V     1
13     W     1
14     Y     1
```

Answer (score 0):

any number of ways

```
test <- c("ASSFGH","PSSWEE","ASSYNT","ASSFRK","ASSFGT","ASSRTV")

# create vector of letters used
individual_characters = unique(unlist(strsplit(Reduce(function(x, y) paste0(x, y), test), '')))
# combine into one string
Reduce(function(x,y) paste0(x,y), individual_characters)
```